# Windows 10 Metro Apps Close Immediately

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui, windows-store-app

Apparently out of the blue, I can't run any metro apps. They open, then close after a few seconds. I tried the fix [here](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/fixing-windows-10-apps-wont-launch-or-hang-apps-splash-screen) but it didn't work. I rarely use metro apps, so I'm not sure when it started. Is there a fix? I have no intentions of re-installing everything.

I checked the event logs, and get this error:

> Activation of app Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed with
>   error: The remote procedure call failed. See the
>   Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

In EventViewer, I looked under *Applications and Services Logs->Microsoft->Windows* but don't see a *TWinUI* folder

...I found *TWinUI* in *Services Logs->Microsoft->Windows->Apps* and the error there is:

> Activation of the app Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App for the
>   Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The remote procedure call
>   failed..

**Update:** Based on a suggestion from another site, I installed the latest DisplayLink driver. This did not help, but when I re-booted, MySql came up with this error:

> There was an error subscribing to WMI Events, this may be caused by a
>   security settings misconfiguration on a local or remote machine.
>
> Call was canceled by the message filter. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010002 (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED))

Not sure if that's related or just a red herring.

**Update:** I actually wrote a small app and just loaded it up in Visual Studio and it wouldn't run. I got this error:

[image]

I did what it said, but still got that error on next attempt.

**Update** I'll add one more piece of information before I give up. I booted into safe mode and got this error:
[image]

Comment: You have UAC set at the default levels?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure. Will have to check...Yes. It is set to _Notify me only when apps try to make changes to my computer (default)_

Comment: You should check for disk corruption (with `chkdsk`) and then run an `SFC /scannow` to ensure system file integrity.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks. Tried it but with no luck.

Comment: This sounds honestly like a group domain problem.  Are you connected to a domain?

Comment: It sounds to me like your firewall or AV is killing RPC, or you have RPC misconfigured.

Comment: @Ramhound No. This is my home office PC.

Comment: @Yorik I've tried disabling AV with no luck. I am guessing there is a configuration error, I just don't know how to fix.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @Dave The first draft was a bit sparse. Downvotes came early. I've been adding info as I try different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the apps working by installing the latest Display Link drivers (7.9M3) released on 2015-10-22 from here: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/sla.php?fileid=171

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the power-shell fix for metro apps. Search for "POWER-SHELL broken windows apps". Mine break like every restart for some reason. This always fixes it for me. Open power-shell as admin and type:

Get-appxprovisionedpackage –online | where-object {$_.packagename –like "*windowscommunicationsapps*"} | remove-appxprovisionedpackage –online

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

takeown /R /F *.*

icacls "c:\Windows" /q /c /t /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":F

icacls "c:\Program Files\WindowsApps" /q /c /t /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":F

Comment: Please explain how this would fix the OP's problem (which was caused by an out of date Display Link driver).